# multiple ajax calls with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax

excuse me sir/ma'am
i'm new to ajax, i'm trying to do multiple ajax call in one function to dislay info after an option in dropdown is selected and it goes into separate field ,something like
a goes into description field, b goes into schedule field
i already got the function for a 1 call but when i'm trying to do 2 it's just doesn't work
here is the code that i made for multiple call

```js
<script>
// multiple ajax calls code that i make
// #paket is the dropdown id
$.when(
    $('#paket').unbind('change');
    $('#paket').change(function(){
        var opt_sel = $('#paket').val();

        $.ajax({
                url:'bttdev3/tour/s1',
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    sel_op:opt_sel
                }   
        }),
        $.ajax({
                url:'bttdev3/tour/s2',
                method: "POST"
                data: {
                    sel_op:opt_sel
                }
        });
    });
);  
    .then(function(a,b){
        $.('#detail').html(a);
        $.('#jadwal').html(b);
    });
</script>
```

here is the previous code that works for 1 data call

```js
<script>
1 call function
(function(){

    $('#paket').unbind('change');
    $('#paket').change(function(){

    var opt_sel = $('#paket').val();  
    var baseurl = "www.dev3.gatra.com/bttdev3";
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST", 
            url: '/bttdev3/tour/s1',
            // url: "/bttdev3/tour/" + s1,

            data:{
                sel_op:opt_sel
            }
        }).done(function(a){

            $('#detail').html(a);
        }).fail(function(){

            alert("gagal memanggil data.");
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
    $(document).on('change', '#packet', function(){
        _ajax('bttdev3/tour/s1', 'POST', {sel_op: $(this).val()}, function(res){
            $('#detail').html(res);
        });

        _ajax('bttdev3/tour/s2', 'POST', {sel_op: $(this).val()}, function(res){
            $('#jadwal').html(res);
        });
    });

    function _ajax(url, method, data, callback){
        $.ajax({
            method, 
            url,
            data
        }).done(function(a){
            if(typeof(callback) != 'undefined'){
                callback (a);   
            }
        }).fail(function(){
            alert("gagal memanggil data.");
        });
    }
```

Comment: excuse me sir what does this do? : function _ajax(url, method, data, callback){
        $.ajax({
            method, 
            url,
            data
        }).done(function(a){
            if(typeof(callback) != 'undefined'){
                callback (a);   
            }
        }).fail(function(){
            alert("gagal memanggil data.");
        });
    }
im just trying to understand the code sir

Comment: on change of #packet in calls _ajax two times the first one for populating content in #detail and the second one populating #jadwal

Comment: oh okay sir, i kinda unserstand a bit now
what about this one : function(res){
            $.('#detail').html(res);
what does the (res) do ?

Comment: res is the data/value return after the ajax request

Comment: i've tried the code but it doesn't work sir, it gives me this error : SyntaxError: missing name after . operator on line : $.('#detail').html(res);

Comment: it works!
at first it gives me the 404 not found error but the calls worked, i tweaked the url a bit to '  _ajax(' tour/s1 ', 'POST', {sel_op: $(this).val()}, function(res){ ' then it worked
thank you for the help sir :)

Comment: my pleasure :).